# ACF repeater field custom image size output

Tags: wordpress, image, foreach, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to output custom image size in my code:

```
                <?php if(get_field('repeater-field-name')) { ?>
                    <?php foreach (get_field('repeater-field-name') as $row) :?>
                        <div class="item" onclick="location.href='<?php print $row['link'] ?>';" style="cursor: pointer;">
                            <div class="sisseviskaja-title"><h2><?php print $row['title'] ?></h2></div>
                            <div class="sisseviskaja-pilt"><img src="<?php print $row['image'] ?>" alt="" /></div>
                        </div>

                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php } ?>
```

I have tried ACF tutorial codes but i'd like to keep foreach loop that i have. I'm no PHP guru so i havent got any good ideas to implement it.

Can someone, please, help me?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way to do with ACF codes. This is using array for the image (which you need to do if you want to pull out the dimensions). I'm not sure exactly if it can be done the way you want to do it.

```
<?php if (have_rows('project_listings')){ ?>
    <?php while (have_rows('project_listings')){ the_row();
        $link = get_sub_field('link_field');
        $title = get_sub_field('title_field');
        $image = get_sub_field('image');
        //additional vars
        $size = 'full';
        $width = $image['sizes'][ $size . '-width' ];
        $height = $image['sizes'][ $size . '-height' ];
                    ?>
    <div class="item" onclick="location.href='<?php echo $link ?>';" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <div class="sisseviskaja-title">
            <h2><?php echo $title ?></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="sisseviskaja-pilt">
            <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" width="<?php echo $width; ?>" height="<?php echo $height; ?>"/>
        </div>
    </div>            
    <?php }; ?>          
<?php }; ?>
```

Comment: This code gives an error, Fatal error: Call to undefined function have_rows()

Comment: Did you replace the field names with your own (as well as the repeater name)?

Comment: Yes, i replaced em. tried to fiddle with it, but still an error. Thought that maybe it doesnt work inside a loop but it doesnt work at all. Even tried your original code with same field names, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this:

```
<?php if( have_rows('field-name') ): ?>
    <?php while( have_rows('field-name') ): the_row();  ?>
        <?php 
            $image = get_sub_field('picture');
            $size = 'thumbnail'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
            if( $image ) {
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );
            } 
        ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```